# Append binary data to Word file

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, add-in

is it possible from Word Add-in (C#) to append arbitrary binary data to the Word DOC/DOCX file and hide it?

Thanks
James

Comment: Why?? How do you want to read/use it?

Answer (score 0):

Docx files are just zips. Maybe you can just added the file?

Comment: No, not 'just' zip files. There is a structuring.